# Scrape longitude and latitude from this html using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use a regex to extract just the longitude and latitude coordinates from this html. This is just a snippet of the full html from http://www.bricodepot.fr/troyes/store/storeDetails.jsp?storeId=1753 so I need to be able to search through the whole targets page html and match the longitude and latitude from this block:

```
<div class="coordinates">
    <i></i>
    <strong>Latitude :</strong> 46.369384765625<strong>Longitude :</strong> 2.56929779052734</div>
</div>
```

This is about as close as I can get at the moment:

```
preg_match("/<strong>Latitude :<\/strong> (.*?)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

which gives:

Array
(
    [0] => **Latitude :** 
    [1] => 
)

Any idea how I can get the cordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there!

```
preg_match_all("<strong>L(at|ong)itude :<\/strong>\s([\w\.]*)?", $input_line, $output_array);
```

And the resulting array will be something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <strong>Latitude :</strong> 46.369384765625
            [1] => <strong>Longitude :</strong> 2.56929779052734
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => at
            [1] => ong
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46.369384765625
            [1] => 2.56929779052734
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, some good answers but this is the solution I ended up using. I like your words of encouragement of almost being there. I wish I understood regex better.

Comment: Good luck @BenPaton! You might check out regex101.com too for learning more about regex ;)

Comment: Had to add a minus infront of the second longitude part as sometimes the longitude is minus. Use regex101.com to test this addition. Good site! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/<strong>Latitude :<\/strong> ([\d\.]+)<strong>Longitude :<\/strong> ([\d\.]+)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do is to [strip the tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) out first. Then your RegExp could be a lot simpler and maintainable.

By stripping the tags, you end up with:

```
Latitude : 46.369384765625Longitude : 2.56929779052734
```

Along with this RegExp:

```
/(?:(Latitude|Longitude) : ([\d\.]+))/
```

You end up with something like this: http://ideone.com/JGZOZi